# Chrome renders colours differently from Safari and Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, colors, rendering

Chrome renders #FF3A00 as #FF0000 for some reason. I included a screenshot from [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L9xy4/) to illustrate the point. The colour that the Color Meter reports (and what I see) differs from what CSS says.

This happens to other colours too. For example, #FFAF00 is rendered as #FFA400 according to the Color Meter.

However, the colours are rendered without problems on Safari and Firefox. I'm on a Mac using Chrome 11, Safari 5 and Firefox 5.

I'm sure there's a logical explanation. Any ideas?

Update: I'm attaching a screenshot of Chrome next to Safari showing the very same page. I checked this image in Photoshop: the colours are #F00 in Chrome and #FF3A00 in Safari.[image: Chrome vs Safari]

[image: Chrome renders #FF3A00 as #F00]

Comment: 2016, 21 century and this issue its still present ...

Comment: 2017 and Chrome 60, issue still happening. Chrome rendering ghost colors. What's the point of spending days designing and picking best colors if Chrome will just decide to use something else!

Comment: It's so funny... 2018 and Chrome 67 still have this issue. 

Comment: 2019 baby! we made it fam.

Comment: faced the issue on chromium today, but why still?

Comment: I might have solved this. Can you look if the solution in my post helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55435873/css-colors-on-os-x-displaying-correctly-in-firefox-but-incorrectly-in-safari-and I think it's to do with the default OS X color profile.

Comment: 2020 here. Chrome 80. Same

Comment: 2021, Chrome 88, Same

Comment: every chrome-based same problem, using Edge and it has the same issue.

Comment: 2022, Chrome 96. Same

Comment: 3050, world war 5 happened, issue still persists

Comment: 2023 - still same - but at least we have this answer for Mac users! https://stackoverflow.com/a/6246569/7549483

Comment: 2023 - Chrome 118. Wasted an hour+ thinking my shader code was wrong. Thanks Google!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I recently posted a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338077/google-chrome-for-mac-css-colors-and-display-profiles

As Andrew Marshall answered there, this is a known issue: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=44872

Comment: I'm now having the exact opposite effect listed in the Chromium issue linked above. Chrome looks good, but Firefox has mis-matched colors. I think this page touches on the issues, but it's a bit beyond me. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=999600

Comment: @Trevor Burnham This issue says "Status: duplicate (closed)". Do you know where I can find the non-closed version of this issue? –

Comment: @mesqueeb Go to the "MergedInto" issue, which is marked as "Fixed (Closed)": https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=667431

Comment: As of 2020, it seems that this is still an issue. I am experiencing it in my Chrome on OS X and the correct colors are on Firefox, whereas Chrome renders wrong RGB values...

Comment: Not sure if there's a browser bug, but in Chrome I had to set force-color-profile to sRGB to match colors of Firefox in Linux, so I filed two issues (not sure which browser has the issue): https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1133990 and https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1668444

Answer (score 54):

Ok, as it turned out, I needed to restart my Chrome. I often connect my macbook air to a 24 inch monitor. It looks like Chrome displays the colours incorrectly when I change to a monitor that's different from what was used when Chrome was started.

I found the answer on the [Google Help forum](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=3de2ee5284399d84&hl=en) : "I should mention that in OS X, every time you change your monitor or monitor profile (e.g. if you switch from your laptop display to your external display), you MUST restart Chrome for it to get the proper monitor profile information from the OS."

Comment: This is a really good answer it needs more exposure in this thread. That problem was driving me insane!

Comment: Yeah! This is the correct answer, why the wrong why is accepted?

Comment: Maybe this solves the problem, or some of the problem for some people, but this doesn't work for me.

Comment: For me this actually does not seem to Apply. Even after re-starting Chrome, color representation is still markedly different.

Answer (score 41):

By default both Firefox and Safari use the sRGB color profile. You must do the same, if your Google Chrome takes a different color profile as default.

1. Access at Chrome: [chrome://flags/#force-color-profile](http://chrome://flags/#force-color-profile)
2. Change **Force color profile** to "**sRGB**".
3. **Relaunch your browser** and testify the rendered colors now.

Answer (score 6):

Mac has color correction set up for your monitor. Your browser may or may not use color correction for web content/images depending on its setup. Your color picker reports what your OS thinks it is rendering. Your browser may report something else.

Color on computers. Something many of us take for granted but never bothered to understand how it is rendered.

Answer (score 5):

In case someone else come here because firefox images looks too colorful (over saturated).
Full guide on how to fix it https://cameratico.com/color-management/firefox/

Shortly:

1. Type in `about:config` on your Firefox address bar
2. Set `gfx.color_management.mode` to `1`
3. Set `gfx.color_management.enablev4` to `true`
4. Restart firefox

Now Firefox will display colors same as Safari, Chrome and all other browsers

Comment: This is nice, but what can I do as a web-developer? I see my website being rendered with different profiles in Chrome and FF... Is there a way to enforce ICC profile from CSS or meta?

Comment: @pavel you should also have 1 additional step: gfx.color_management.native_srgb should be set to 'true'. The article you posted says that "It's not needed anymore to change any advanced config in order to properly enable color management." However, when I delved into the config settings, thinking that I may have adjusted them, in my past life as a UK colour management consultant! I found that I needed to change the boolean value of the native_srgb setting. Once I did that, the tests that the article provides worked perfectly. I'm still having an issue with chrome on ProPhotoRGB Vs sRGB test!

Answer (score 3):

Chrome color picker works by taking color from current monitor color profile,and the problem may happens by changing color setting or sometime change monitor, please check the below method to solve.

Go to chrome://flags/#force-color-profile and click Reset all to default

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I changed the Colour Profile in OS X and that sorted it for me.

See the screenshots below using different Color Profile. Note, in the screenshots I'm trying to differentiate between `#ff00ff`, `#ff1aff`, `#ff33ff` and `#ff4dff`. It's only when I don't choose the default OS X colour profile that I can differentiate the colours correctly.

Default colour profile:

[image: with default profile]

With a different colour profile:

[image: with sRGB ICE61966-2.1 profile]

From: [CSS colors on OS X displaying correctly in Firefox but incorrectly in Safari and Chrome (potentially 'solved')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55435873/css-colors-on-os-x-displaying-correctly-in-firefox-but-incorrectly-in-safari-and)

I found Safari and Chrome could not differentiate between `#ff00ff`, `#ff1aff`, `#ff33ff` and `#ff4dff`. But Firefox could. In addition Inkscape, an X11 app, could. But Gimp and Libreoffice Writer, non X11 apps, could not. Firefox and X11 apps seem to be using their own colour profile somehow.

I have no idea why Mac defaults to `Color LCD` profile which does not do this differentiation amongst others.

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem with Chrome (Lubuntu) when exporting a PNG in Photoshop. Solution: File -> Save As -> Uncheck "*ICC Profile: Adobe RGB (1998)*".