# Different display color in Chrome and Safari

Tags: css, colors, safari, background-color

My problem concerns color display.

[image: visible difference]

I have `#0565af` colour image inside rounded box with `background-color: #0565af;`. In Safari I see two different colors. The attached picture shows the difference. How can I eliminate this difference?

Comment: Not seeing difference?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome renders colours differently from Safari and Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237455/chrome-renders-colours-differently-from-safari-and-firefox)

Answer (score 1):

Generally, browsers interpret color in different ways according to how it is written. Meanwhile some browsers prefer the most commonly used HEX nomenclature, other browsers interpret sRGB by calculating the different hues of base colors and going from there. A rule of thumb I apply professionally when in doubt is to declare both the HEX code and sRGB code into the CSS. If you are using LESS or SCSS, then you can integrate these into one mixin and render it as such.

So a normal black color, would be coded as:

```
.class{
   color:#000;
   color: #000000;
   color: rgb(0,0,0);
}
```

Refer to these links for more explanation on this known problem

[Numerical color values](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color-3/#numerical)

[Colors in sRGB](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color/#sRGB)

And use this great tool to help you find the values you are looking for:

[ColorHexa](http://www.colorhexa.com/)

Comment: Even if I change `#0565af` to WEB `#006699` or RBG `rgb(5,101,175)` I still see the difference. 
When I check result in Photoshop by color picker, it shows me that:
`#006699` becomes `#00649c` but
`rgb(5,101,175)` becomes `#005fb2`.

Probably only remains for me to adjust the image to the Web safe.

Thank you for a substantive answer and Happy New Year :)

Comment: This is kinda pointless—even if it were true that hex and rgba triplets were treated differently, having multiple "color" attributes will simply override the previous ones. Whichever one is specified last is the one that will be used, regardless of browser.