# Color difference between browsers (Chromium, Chrome, Firefox) with example

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, rendering, chromium

I'm working in a web project and I'm awfully amazed of the color difference between browsers (Chromium, Chrome, Firefox).

[Comparative on Chromium, Chrome and Firefox, in this respective order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFlg5.jpg)

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04, but this is happening too on Windows, I've seen is somewhere a Safari/Mac usual trouble, but can't find nothing related to this problem.

Is there any way to solve/correct it? Or is it related to the rendering workflow/process of each browser?

Color correction should be a standard not a war. UI/UX devs could agree on me.

Comment: color-management is non-trivial. Do the images have embedded ICC profiles? Do you have an ICC profile configured for your monitor? Have you enabled/disabled color management in your browser? the simplest solution is to convert to sRGB and ensure the image metadata indicates that too

Comment: Well, it's a point, will look for that, but anyway... t's ok to ask this for a designer or a dev, but does each user or client need to know that? they are going to stare at some different screens with some different profiles on some different browsers and they want to look approximately the same not this quite big jump. 

Should I need to explain that to every client/user of my works? Makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [Chrome renders colours differently from Safari and Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237455/chrome-renders-colours-differently-from-safari-and-firefox/50465374#50465374) this might help explain and satisfy your customers :

By default both Firefox and Safari use the sRGB color profile. You must do the same, if your Google Chrome takes a different color profile as default.

1. Access at Chrome: chrome://flags/#force-color-profile
2. Change Force color profile to "sRGB".
3. Relaunch your browser and testify the rendered colors now.