# How to get correct adjusted CSS Color code of chrome rendered color?

Tags: css, colors, photoshop, uicolor, color-picker

I am designing a website and seeking inspiration from other sites.

When I visit a site in chrome (on mac), use eye dropper on an item, and use the color on my website, the color is different. How can I get the color I see to show on my site the same? Whats the process to use? Any tools to help?

I was thinking the issue was browser rendering different, but chrome and safari both show same color:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NLmpgJ

CSS color:

```
  background-color: rgba(22, 39, 56, 1.0);
```

Browser rendered color:

```
  background-color: rgba(18, 29, 43, 1.0);
```

So lets say I want my (rendered) site color to be (18, 29, 43), how can I determine the CSS color to give that output? (in this case the answer would be 22, 39, 56).

See screenshot for explanation of my confusion:
[image]

---

Revised question summary:

I am seeking a formula/ tool in which I can input chrome rendered color codes and return the color code needed to pass to chrome to render that color.

Comment: duplicate?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237455/chrome-renders-colours-differently-from-safari-and-firefox

Comment: @NilesTanner Thanks, I saw that before posting. It seems similar, but from what I can tell its not, and have been unable to find any answer to my question on that page. I am using a laptop so this is not a multiple monitor issue. There is a lot of information there though, I will keep researching it

Comment: @NilesTanner So I took a look at the codepen on firefox and color shows correctly there, so the possible duplicate is discussing the same problem, but not asking for the same answer. I am seeking a way to identify the color code to give to chrome/ safari to match the "real" color. When I check twitter.com in all 3 browsers, their colors all show the same, so there must be a way.

Comment: What version of chrome are you using?

Comment: Version 68.0.3440.106 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Actually I was mistaken, twitter colors are not rendered the same in firefox vs chrome. I think I just have to use trial and error and give different colors for different browsers to get them all to display "similar". I am doubting there is a formula out there the convert chrome/ Safari RBG to Firefox/ real RGB

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer:

> just take screenshots and use picker in Firefox and plug those values
>   into CSS.

Chrome should consistently render the colors incorrectly, thus matching the initial observed incorrect color rendered.

Since Firefox renders in real RGB colors, the solution is to just go to the source color provided by a working browser (firefox).

This wont work if the website uses different colors for different browsers, but otherwise works perfectly.