# CSS colors on OS X displaying incorrectly in Safari and Chrome but correctly in Firefox (potentially 'solved')

Tags: macos, google-chrome, firefox, colors, safari

If you look at this page: https://www.color-hex.com/color/ff00ff and scroll down you see "Monochromatic Colors of #ff00ff".

The last four colours there are `#ff00ff`, `#ff1aff`, `#ff33ff` and `#ff4dff`. (The HSB values are `hsb(300, 100, 100)`, `hsb(300, 90, 100)`, `hsb(300, 80, 100)`, `hsb(300, 70, 100)`. The HSL values are `hsl(300, 100, 50)`, `hsl(300, 100, 55)`, `hsl(300, 100, 60)`, `hsl(300, 100, 65)`)

In Firefox it looks like this:

[image: Firefox]

In Chrome it looks like this:

[image: Chrome]

In Safari it looks like this:

[image: Safari]

In Chrome and Safari `#ff00ff`, `#ff1aff`, `#ff33ff` and `#ff4dff` all look like the same colour.

Using the colour picker in Preview to click on the `#ff1aff` colour block, I see that in Chrome and Safari `#ff1aff`is actually `#ff00ff`. The same with all the other colour blocks too.

In Chrome:

[image]

In Safari:

[image]

Only in Firefox is the `#ff1aff` actually `#ff1aff`:

[image]

Why does only Firefox properly differentiate between these colours? And why does Safari and Chrome not?

My web browser versions:

- Firefox: 66.0.2 (2019-03-17)
- Chrome: 73.0.3683.86
- Safari: 12.1 - 13607.1.40.1.5

Strangely, I cannot get Gimp to differentiate between `ff00ff` and `ff33ff`. Nor can I get LibreOffice writer to differentiate. But I can get Inkscape to do so. Inkscape is an X11 app. Neither Gimp or Inkscape are X11 apps.

My OS:

- OS X 10.13.6

This seems to be a OS X issue because on my Ubuntu machine things are fine in both Chromium 70 and Firefox 65.

---

Edit: Potentially 'solved'

I opened up the Color section in Settings. My display profile is `Color LCD`. This profile was created by Apple. I have not modified it. I'll include a screenshot with the colours blocks above it:

[image: with Color LCD profile]

(Note, the calibrated version also doesn't show the colour differentiation)

But if I change to another profile I see the colour differentiation. If I choose `sRGB ICE61966-2.1`, a profile created by HP apparently, my colours appear like they do in Firefox:

[image: with sRGB ICE61966-2.1 profile]

So why does my Macbook come with a default colour profile that doesn't differentiate between `#ff00ff`, `#ff1aff`, `#ff33ff` and `#ff4dff` amongst other colours?

Comment: Do you use MAC?

Comment: It says in the post I use Mac OS X, yes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome renders colours differently from Safari and Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237455/chrome-renders-colours-differently-from-safari-and-firefox)

Comment: I saw https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237455/chrome-renders-colours-differently-from-safari-and-firefox but the linked to bug has been closed. It seems a solved issue, that one at least. And that post claims that Chrome renders differently to Safari, which isn't the case here.

Comment: sRGB  mat not match your monitor profile. Try other options too.

Comment: I've tried them all. None of them work.