# SVG colors only displaying correctly in firefox

Tags: html, css, svg

So i was doing a cross browser check for my website redesign and I noticed that only in Firefox were my SVG colors displaying how they looked when I exported them from Adobe XD. Everywhere else (mobile included) they are super saturated. Any ideas on what my be causing this? You can see my site at:

https://tester.desertsunstudio.com

Here are some screenshots as requested:

**Chrome**

[image: homepage top]

[image: homepage bottom]

**Firefox**

[image: homepagetop]

[image: homepagebottom]

**SVG of portfolio picture**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 716 456.561">
  <g transform="translate(-1084 -2280)">
    <path d="M496.622,248.169H485.936a51.572,51.572,0,0,0,25-44.185h0a51.655,51.655,0,0,0-51.655-51.655H390.108a51.571,51.571,0,0,0,25-44.185h0a51.654,51.654,0,0,0-51.655-51.655H76.845A51.654,51.654,0,0,0,25.19,108.143h0a51.571,51.571,0,0,0,25,44.185H12.441a51.655,51.655,0,0,0-51.655,51.655h0a51.655,51.655,0,0,0,51.655,51.655H23.127a51.572,51.572,0,0,0-25,44.185h0A51.656,51.656,0,0,0,49.782,351.48H256.419c-6.014,8.6-9.346,18.042-9.346,27.949,0,40.034,54.248,72.488,121.167,72.488s121.167-32.454,121.167-72.488c0-9.907-3.332-19.348-9.346-27.949h16.561a51.655,51.655,0,0,0,51.655-51.656h0A51.655,51.655,0,0,0,496.622,248.169Z" transform="translate(1123.214 2223.512)" fill="#f7941d"/>
    <rect width="152.042" height="51.655" rx="25.828" transform="translate(1568.414 2280)" fill="#643282"/>
    <rect width="152.042" height="51.655" rx="25.828" transform="translate(1121.341 2615.107)" fill="#4f1c6c"/>
    <circle cx="24.845" cy="24.845" r="24.845" transform="translate(1121.341 2686.87)" fill="#4f1c6c"/>
    <circle cx="24.845" cy="24.845" r="24.845" transform="translate(1750.309 2280.982)" fill="#643282"/>
    <path d="M4.69,274.694H541.734a51.618,51.618,0,0,0-45.112-26.525H485.936a51.572,51.572,0,0,0,25-44.185h0a51.655,51.655,0,0,0-51.655-51.655H390.108a51.571,51.571,0,0,0,25-44.185h0a51.654,51.654,0,0,0-51.655-51.655H76.845A51.654,51.654,0,0,0,25.19,108.143h0a51.571,51.571,0,0,0,25,44.185H12.441a51.655,51.655,0,0,0-51.655,51.655h0a51.655,51.655,0,0,0,51.655,51.655H23.127A52.028,52.028,0,0,0,4.69,274.694Z" transform="translate(1123.214 2223.512)" fill="#643282"/>
    <path d="M496.622,248.169H485.936a51.572,51.572,0,0,0,25-44.185h0a51.576,51.576,0,0,0-25.249-44.336l-2.548,30.9-4.6,9.849-9.848,3.283V185.347l-10.506,11.144v63.657l-156.736-8.74L283.534,211.56l6.566-32.173V149.84h-7.222l-5.244,28.89h-5.926V146.557L264.493,135.4l-13.233.656v-5.909l-13.687-9.192v56.467L228.38,180.7V141.961l-9.849-.657v19.041l-5.252,13.132-9.849,9.193-8.536,13.821-23.638-4.629-11.072,18.669-10.016-2.276-16.337-42.664H123.325l-3.283-23.63-10.5-1.314-15.1,13.789-2.627,17.071-9.192-.656V133.425h-3.94v-9.849l-16.414-5.909V103.878l-23.638-1.313,1.662,41.982a52.074,52.074,0,0,0,9.9,7.781h-9.6l7.223,22.462-5.253,2.627L31.4,196.491l-15.759,7.846V152.328h-3.2a51.655,51.655,0,0,0-51.655,51.655h0a51.655,51.655,0,0,0,51.655,51.655H23.127A52.028,52.028,0,0,0,4.69,274.694H541.734A51.618,51.618,0,0,0,496.622,248.169Z" transform="translate(1123.214 2223.512)" fill="#20376d"/>
    <circle cx="24.845" cy="24.845" r="24.845" transform="translate(1267.908 2302.845)" fill="#a36d00"/>
    <path d="M12.441,255.639H23.127a51.572,51.572,0,0,0-25,44.185h0a51.655,51.655,0,0,0,51.655,51.655H256.419c-6.014,8.6-9.346,18.042-9.346,27.95,0,40.034,54.248,72.488,121.167,72.488s121.167-32.454,121.167-72.488c0-9.908-3.332-19.348-9.346-27.95h16.561a51.654,51.654,0,0,0,51.655-51.655h0a51.655,51.655,0,0,0-51.655-51.655H485.936a52.11,52.11,0,0,0,14.224-12.686c-26.076-15.543-57.425-38.993-84.014-38.993-74.2,0-108.163,44.02-155.956,44.02s-69.174-32.7-144.636-36.473C62.9,201.4,22.9,228.416-4.861,252.606A51.458,51.458,0,0,0,12.441,255.639Z" transform="translate(1123.214 2223.512)" fill="#390a54"/>
    <path d="M338.168,265.45c-47.793,0-100.617,53.038-130.8,53.038s-45.277-32.7-104.389-32.7c-35.848,0-72.594,24.041-95.987,42.973a51.6,51.6,0,0,0,42.791,22.718H256.419c-6.014,8.6-9.346,18.042-9.346,27.95,0,40.034,54.248,72.488,121.167,72.488s121.167-32.454,121.167-72.488c0-9.908-3.332-19.348-9.346-27.95h16.561a51.654,51.654,0,0,0,51.655-51.655h0a51.793,51.793,0,0,0-.837-9.023C528.951,302.673,500.816,317.23,474,317.23,428.723,317.23,385.961,265.45,338.168,265.45Z" transform="translate(1123.214 2223.512)" fill="#4f1c6c"/>
    <path d="M381.8,395.676v27.666L403.3,408.859V379.227H381.8Z" transform="translate(1132.214 2210.512)" fill="#312100"/>
    <path d="M381.8,365.833V393.5L403.3,379.227v-23.3H381.8Z" transform="translate(1132.214 2210.512)" fill="#5a3900"/>
    <path d="M318.327,317.036v52.5L382.2,423.09v-52.5" transform="translate(1132.214 2210.512)" fill="#5a3900"/>
    <path d="M318.327,317.036,382.2,370.59,403.3,355.925l-62.274-52.5Z" transform="translate(1132.214 2210.512)" fill="#a7780f"/>
    <path d="M318.327,339.945v29.591L382.2,423.09V393.5" transform="translate(1132.214 2210.512)" fill="#312100"/>
    <path d="M330.117,346.571v7.854l9.555,8.011v-7.854" transform="translate(1132.214 2210.512)" fill="#c29844"/>
    <path d="M357.069,369.281v7.854l9.555,8.011v-7.854" transform="translate(1132.214 2210.512)" fill="#c29844"/>
    <path d="M347.15,327.124l1.492-9.992a5.834,5.834,0,0,1,9.61-3.531l17.565,15.354a5.815,5.815,0,0,1,1.923,5.235l-1.726,11.633a3.021,3.021,0,0,1-5.014,1.8l-2.4-2.176,0-.006,1.644-11.085-15.14-14.2-1.156,7.741a2.741,2.741,0,0,1-4.716,1.463l-2.071-2.224Z" transform="translate(1132.214 2210.512)" fill="#332100"/>
    <path d="M294.88,388.464l.757-12.528,7.292-4.153,3.477-4.161,10.456-2.763,10.381,7.538,4.085,8.724,2.323,8.793-6.488,5.273-20.029.208Z" transform="translate(1132.214 2210.512)" fill="#7e5708"/>
    <path d="M327.792,394.676l5.86-4.763-2.323-8.793-2.937-6.273-4.6,4.7Z" transform="translate(1132.214 2210.512)" fill="#a27823"/>
    <path d="M327.244,372.4l-10.381-7.538-10.456,2.763-3.477,4.161-.582.331,4.825,3.217,5.335,7.2,10.091,1.147,8.15-3.8Z" transform="translate(1132.214 2210.512)" fill="#c29844"/>
    <path d="M313.305,405.786l2.638-3.449H320l3.348,3.043-.406,5.681-6.188-2.029Z" transform="translate(1132.214 2210.512)" fill="#7e5708"/>
    <path d="M293.156,397.467l-2.333,4.768,4.87,4.971,3.246-1.623-2.739-4.261Z" transform="translate(1132.214 2210.512)" fill="#7e5708"/>
    <path d="M300.1,354.061l2.942,1.369,1.371,3.348,3.218-1.826-1.951-3.878Z" transform="translate(1132.214 2210.512)" fill="#7e5708"/>
    <path d="M369.572,427.184l8.05,4.616,14.126,1.619,12.949-5.15-1.471-3.99-5.886-1.013-3.973-7.357-4.562-2.691L376.446,417.3l-4.12,4.2Z" transform="translate(1132.214 2210.512)" fill="#7e5708"/>
    <path d="M403.227,424.278l-5.886-1.013-3.973-7.358-4.562-2.691-1.019.337.725,4.708-3.973,1.838-.441,4.178,4.414,2.813-1.03,2.06-1.552,3.6,5.819.667,12.949-5.15Z" transform="translate(1132.214 2210.512)" fill="#c29844"/>
    <path d="M406.938,417.485l6.954-1.512-4.334-3.427-3.225,2.469Z" transform="translate(1132.214 2210.512)" fill="#7e5708"/>
    <path d="M376.169,438.486,372.54,440.6l-3.931-3.528,5.846-1.613Z" transform="translate(1132.214 2210.512)" fill="#7e5708"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Please include your SVG in your question. You might also like to include some screenshots. Without those, when you fix (or remove) your site, this question and any answers will probably become useless to future readers.

Comment: Also, which colours do you think are wrong? They look identical to me in Chrome & FF on Win10.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau added the screenshots and svg file. Thank you for looking it over; the differences are subtle, but are most notable in the purple portfolio image.

Comment: I used my color picker extension in both Chrome and Firefox and they are both reporting the same exact colors for the portfolio image.

Comment: @APAD1 thanks for looking it over. I saw the same hex codes as well; but as you can see from the screenshots they are displaying differently.

Comment: The entire screenshot(including the background color) looks different. I doubt this is an issue with the code.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @APAD1. The purple sky in your "Portfolio" image has `fill="#643282"`.  Which is what the Firefox screenshot has. But in the Chrome screenshot, that sky colour is `#6e1783`. So it seems some something related to colour management is happening, and causing your colours to be modified by Chrome.

I'm not a regular Mac user, but this question seems like it might be relevant:

[CSS colors on OS X displaying incorrectly in Safari and Chrome but correctly in Firefox (potentially 'solved')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55435873/css-colors-on-os-x-displaying-incorrectly-in-safari-and-chrome-but-correctly-in)

Try going into your display settings and changing your "Display profile" to sRGB.