# svg color "wrong" in chrome with color profile "default" on some screens

Tags: css, google-chrome, svg

We have svg-images on a new website. The 'blue' color on my laptop  is rendered as #aebae2 (174,186,226) in all my browsers (firefox, chrome, edge):
http://test.exploredesign.de/stelacon/index.php/en/dms-en

Here is the 'blue' part of the svg: 
[image: n]

A collegue has a laptop where chrome renders it a little bit different (175,178,227).

For example here is an old similar case:
[Chrome renders colours differently from Safari and Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237455/chrome-renders-colours-differently-from-safari-and-firefox)
And really, if the the collegue changes chrome://flags/#force-color-profile from default to "sRGB" ... chrome renders the color as #aebae2 (174,186,226).

Can I change the svg or the css of the website that chrome or better all browsers always render the color as #aebae2 (174,186,226)?
Or can I find similar colors that are less color-profile-dependent?

Comment: Is your colleague using the same version of Chrome? Have you tried in Incognito mode?

Comment: There was a spec to allow you to set the color profile, but for some reason they dropped it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/color-profile

Comment: The colleague uses the same (current) version of Chrome.

Comment: I found another hint here: If you are designing purely for the web you should be working in sRGB IEC61966-2.1. But it will take some time to test this because I have not created the svg.
https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/67610/illustrator-cs6-changes-colours-when-saving-as-png-or-svg